# angular 2 default route gets changed to child route

Tags: angular2-routing

I am having an issue with the default route, earlier it used to work properly but now when I hit the domain name/root page, it gets redirected to authenticated dashboard page which is a Lazy Load NgModule and again gets redirected to login page as he does not have any credentials for authenticated user.

Why is this happening, recently I have moved to angular 4.1.2 - but I am pretty much sure that it was working fine earlier and angular v2 to v4 isnt the real cause of the problem.

my routes are :

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/adviser/login/login.component';
// import { DashboardModule } from './pages/adviser/dashboard/dashboard.module'
import { Page404Component } from './pages/page404/page404.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './shared/services/auth-guard.service';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';
import { TermsConditionComponent } from './pages/terms-condition/terms-condition.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'privacy-policy', component: PrivacyPolicyComponent },
  { path: 'terms-condition', component: TermsConditionComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], loadChildren: 'app/pages/adviser/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: 'funds', loadChildren: 'app/pages/funds/funds.module#FundsModule' },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/home' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: Page404Component }
];
```

My app.module is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, BrowserXhr } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './app.routes';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './pages/contact/contact.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/adviser/login/login.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './pages/adviser/dashboard/dashboard.module';
import { Page404Component } from './pages/page404/page404.component';
import { HttpService } from './shared/services/http.service';
import { InstrumentService } from './shared/services/instrument.service';
import { WindowRef } from './shared/services/window-ref.service';
import { CredentialsService } from './shared/services/credentials.service';
import { ConstantService } from './shared/services/constant.service';
import { CryptService } from './shared/services/crypt.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './shared/services/auth-guard.service';
import { PrivacyPolicyComponent } from './pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.component';
import { TermsConditionComponent } from './pages/terms-condition/terms-condition.component';
import { NgProgressModule, NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import { Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    Page404Component,
    PrivacyPolicyComponent,
    TermsConditionComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgProgressModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    Ng2PageScrollModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DashboardModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [HttpService, CredentialsService, ConstantService,
    AuthGuardService, CryptService, WindowRef,InstrumentService,
    { provide: BrowserXhr, useClass: NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My Dashbaord.module is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpService } from '../../../shared/services/http.service';
import { InstrumentService } from '../../../shared/services/instrument.service';
import { WindowRef } from '../../../shared/services/window-ref.service';
import { CredentialsService } from '../../../shared/services/credentials.service';
import { ConstantService } from '../../../shared/services/constant.service';
import { CryptService } from '../../../shared/services/crypt.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from '../../../shared/services/auth-guard.service';
import { AutoCompleteComponent } from '../../../shared/plugin/auto-complete/auto-complete.component';
import { MilliToDatePipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/milli-to-date.pipe';
import { PercentagePipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/percentage.pipe';
import { NseBsePipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/nse-bse.pipe';
import { INRCurrencyPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/inr-currency.pipe';
import { NumberFormatPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/num.pipe';
import { RiskPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/risk.pipe';
import { LogPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/log.pipe';
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';
import { NgProgressModule, NgProgressCustomBrowserXhr } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import { Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll';
import { InstrumentPipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/instrument.pipe';
import { TruncatePipe } from '../../../shared/pipes/truncate.pipe';

import { DashboardComponent} from './dashboard.component';
import { dashboardRouting } from './dashboard.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    dashboardRouting,
    ChartsModule,
    FormsModule    
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    AutoCompleteComponent,
    MilliToDatePipe,
    PercentagePipe,
    NumberFormatPipe,
    INRCurrencyPipe,
    NseBsePipe,
    RiskPipe,
    LogPipe,
    InstrumentPipe,
    TruncatePipe
  ],
  providers: [HttpService, CredentialsService, ConstantService,
    AuthGuardService, CryptService, WindowRef, InstrumentService]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

My dashboard routing is

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

const dashboardRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }  
];

export const dashboardRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(dashboardRoutes);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by removing  following imports from app.module.ts file

1. DashboardModule
2. FundsModule

as this 2 were being lazy loaded and therefore were creating an issue